# Grammar that is LR(1) but not LL(1)

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar

This might look like a basic question to some of you but I expect intelligent replies here.

Why can't a LR(1) grammar with `left recursion` or the LR(1) grammar that is **not** `left factored` be LL(1)?

Comment: do someone expect replies which are not intelligent??

Comment: @Francesco: That is a better question. xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can never expect the termination of the string in LR(1) with left recursion.